# Enabling History API with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html5-history

I have a `dataTable` object on a page representing a list of releases I need to keep track of with the url `/releases` I want to add the following functionality

1. if `/releases?query=<query>`,  the `dataTable` will initialized with the provided query
2. The `query` parameter is updated if the user changes the search term
3. The back and forward buttons in the browser go the appropriate query

So far I am able to do the first 2, but when I listen for the `popstate` event, redrawing the table triggers a `pushState` which I can't figure out how to prevent. Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var prevSearch;
  var table = $('#releases').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength" : 50,
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": '#{params[:query]}'},
    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
        var curSearch = oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch;
        if (!prevSearch) {
          prevSearch = curSearch;
        } else if (curSearch != prevSearch) {
          console.log("changed to: " + curSearch);
          history.pushState({query: curSearch}, "title", "releases?query=" + curSearch);
          prevSearch = curSearch;
        }
     }
  });
  window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    if (e.state) {
      table.fnFilter(e.state.query);          
    }
  });
});
```

Note, I am using a `rails` backend and this is inlined javascript being served in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have only 2 options here:

- move pushState code out of drawCallback. There must be some other code that causes the datatables to draw when user enters something. put your pushState code there. This is the ideal solution
- add a hack like this

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var prevSearch;
      var saveState = true;
      var table = $('#releases').dataTable({
          "bJQueryUI":true,
          "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
          "iDisplayLength":50,
          "oSearch":{"sSearch":'#{params[:query]}'},
          "fnDrawCallback":function (oSettings) {
              var curSearch = oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch;
              if (!prevSearch) {
                  prevSearch = curSearch;
              } else if (curSearch != prevSearch) {
                  console.log("changed to: " + curSearch);
                  if (saveState) {
                      history.pushState({query:curSearch}, "title", "releases?query=" + curSearch);
                  }
                  prevSearch = curSearch;
              }
          }
      });
      window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
          if (e.state) {
              saveState = false;
              table.fnFilter(e.state.query);
              saveState = true;
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Comment: I have been looking for another, more appropriate, callback to put the pushState code in, but I can't seem to find one. I ended up implementing a solution similar to your 2nd one, but I'd really appreciate help in finding the proper callback solution.

Comment: where is the user entering the search term? i assume its an input. does the table get updated as they time or when they press enter? either way you can bind event listeners to that inputbox and move your pushstate function into there

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I was hoping for something that is part of the datatable API. I don't want to reach into elements that the datatable plugin controls.

Comment: thats the problem, you are probably using their default search box for searching.. so that the only way in that case. you could implement that same searchbox yourself if you wanted to. you just need to call the fnFilter(term) function but functionally it will be the same